# Hibernate entity класс без ID

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть БД `Oracle` на структуру, которой я не могу повлиять.

В БД есть таблица org (с полями code, name, okato) без первичного ключа.
Также есть таблица police, которая содержит поле org

В таблице `police` для некоторых записей в поле org содержится значение (org.code)

Как через `Hiberate` создать `entity` класс, который не имеет поля `ID`?

Если создать класс без поля ID ругается

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No
> identifier specified for entity: entity.Org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать сущности в `Hibernate` используя составные ключи из других полей. Если обычно мы `id` подразумеваем как уникальный ключ доступа, то в случае с составным необходимо будет создать ключ из других, имеющихся полей.

**Пример:**

*Класс ID:*

```java
@Embeddable
public class BookId implements Serializable {

    private String author;
    private String name;
}
```

*Класс, где используется составной ключ ID:*

```java
@Entity
public class Book {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BookId id;
    private String genre;
    private Integer price;
}
```

Более подробно см.[здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-embedded-method-parameters)